# slideUp/Down using jquery from one section of a page to another

Tags: jquery, transition, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to use the slideUp and Down effect to transition between sections of the same webpage. Basically, I set up

My code for the HTML, CSS, and JQuery can be seen on jsfiddle: 
(http://jsfiddle.net/dbartolome/2s0jy72q/1/)

```
   $("#work").click(function(){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("header").slideDown(700);
```

**Update:** I found this thing called scroll to anchor online. What are your thoughts? I don't understand a part of their code.  This is their jsfiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/BjpWB/4/)

```
    function scrollToAnchor(aid){
     var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
     }

     $("#link").click(function() {
     scrollToAnchor('id3');
    });
```

I got lost with the content for function scrollToAnchor(aid)

Comment: After a quick glance at the fiddle, I think it's worth mentioning that everything between your `html` and `head` tag should be IN the `head` tag.

Comment: You might want to use [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: Regarding you're update, it is close to what you are looking for but tailored to someone's markup..

Comment: ps `slideDown` slides the selected element down, not to be construded  with sliding down to the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the position of the section with offset and animate scrollTop down to the element's top point

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetID = $(this).attr('href')
    var elementPosition = $(targetID).offset().top
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: elementPosition},'slow');
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/2s0jy72q/4/)

It works up or down, so you can even use this to add a "Back to Top" link

```
<header id="top">...</header>
```

Just link to `#top`

```
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

In the example and above code, notice that the `href` of the link is the `id` of where it scrolls to

---

In the jquery code, it takes the `href`  of the clicked `a` and selects the element with an ID equal to it. The code then finds the top offset point of the element with that id, and animates `scrollTop` to it.

**References**

- [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - used for CSS property animation, also find `scrollTop` explanation in there
- [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - used to get the `href` value
- [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) - used to find the top position of the element within the document scope.
- [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  - used to listen for a click before performing the scroll - same as [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Ooh thanks! Especially for doing the "back to top" as well! I'm going to study this.

Comment: No problem, just added a references section to my answer to help you in your studies :)

Comment: I used codeacademy to get a basic overview of jquery...what did you use to get a deeper understanding or more exercises for learning this?

Comment: I started with things like code academy, be sure to check out http://learn.jquery.com/. The one thing that sped up my learning was trying to answer questions on here and being presented with scenarios Ive never encountered. Sometimes you know, sometimes you research the topic a little, sometimes you get beaten to the punch but you atleast see the answer and learn from it, tried some things you're familiar with and researched some things you're not.

Comment: Thanks--will check out that site. Brian, the js code doesn't work outside of jsfiddle. Also, I noticed that on Stackoverflow, you have two lines that aren't in the jsfiddle for the javascript bit. Is it possible for you to explain what the lines are saying starting from var targetID?

Comment: I updated my example link, it was the same code just formatted differently. It will work as long as wherever you want to scroll to `<header id="top">...</header>` has an `id=""` and whatever you want to scroll with `<a href="#top">Back to top</a>` has an `href` that is that `id` with a hashtag

Comment: Thanks so much everyone but especially you, Brian! I finally got it to work offline. (I had to include the jquery library in the html). I am giddy with excitement!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the href tags to call the ids of the parts you want to show.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
   $(link).slideUp(700);
});
```

This will use the '#' from your link as the '#' needed for your selector of id tags.

It would work best if you give a class to just the a tags you will be using as well place that in your jquery call to those tags. Otherwise. You will stop the default action of all your a tags.

```
$('a.myClass').on('click', function(e){
```

I changed .click to .on because it is a much cleaner way of binding events to your function and allows flexibly for you down the road.

$(this) in the function is referring to the specific a tag you are clicking.

Lastly, when using selectors to look for an element with and id, you want to be sure and use a '#' before the name of the id and '.' before the name of a class.

**RESPONSE TO QUESTION**

You could use 'work' instead. The words 'link' and 'work' are both just variables. So, you can name it whatever you would like to but that will not change anything as long as you are using that same name wherever you want to use the information which this variable contains. You could call it x or z and it would still work.

The part that really matters is what the variable is equal to. In the function I created, the variable is equal to the link you have stored within the href tag of any link you click.

If you click the 'work' link in you nav the variable 'link' is equal to '#work' because that is the value of your href in that navigation item.  Likewise, if you then click on the next nav item over, the variable 'link' would then equal the href within that item.

The reason I used it is to allow you to write less code in the long run and not have to come back and edit this jquery function when you add more links to your nav and more sections to your page.

Comment: ^so instead of link, I write in something like var work = $(this).attr('href'); I tried it in fiddle with "link" so I'm thinking I have to change link to the names I used

Comment: Please see answer for your question above